# How to convert an output from a defined function to a list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, function, while-loop

So I have the following code my goal is to make a list for the cases when cats = 10,100,1,0,21 and 321 so I wanted to start easy and do the cats = 10. The output is always a number squared, so when cats = 10, the output should be printed in a list "[1,4,9]" when cats = 21 then the output should be "[1,4,9,16]" etc, so when cats = n in the list there should not be a number that is greater than n. The actual output is for example 1 4 9 but printed on a separate line but as mentioned i want them in a list. I also tried array but no luck unfortunately.

```
CATS = 10
def test(cats=CATS):
    x=1
    n=1
    while cats>=n:
        print(n)
        x+=1
        n+=1
        n=x**2
test()
# [x*x for x in range(1,4)] is unfortunately not an option
```

Comment: Currently your function is not returning any values, only printing. You could try appending the values of n to a list and then return the list upon completion of the while loop.

Comment: But how do I do that? I have also thought of that but in order to append I need an already existing list and if I tried to do so without a list a NameError would appear in which it would say that "X" is not defined.

Comment: You need to explain more clearly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want to build an algorithm, with a defined function using a while loop, where the N squared is added into a list and eventually printed. So in this example "def test(cats=CATS)" it means for def test(10) so at the end in the list there should not be a number bigger than the Nth number in the "def test(n)"

Answer (score 0):

This code will help for the functionality you explained :

```
def print_squares(num):
  print([i*i for i in range(1, num) if i*i < num])

numbers = [10,100,1,0,21, 321]

print_squares(numbers[4])
print_squares(numbers[0])
```

Outputs :

```
>>> numbers = [10,100,1,0,21, 321]
>>> print_squares(numbers[4])
[1, 4, 9, 16]
>>> print_squares(numbers[0])
[1, 4, 9]
>>>
```

Comment: But as it states in my comment, this would not be an option because only one number is given, in that example would be CATS = 10 so my function test(cats=CATS) would be like test(10). and the answer would be "[1,4,9]", But for example when test(cats=21) then the answer should be "[1,4,9,16]"

Comment: @helplessstudent edited my answer to work as function for single number that you pass . you can try this

Comment: Actually I am looking for something like the other answer using a while loop and an empty list, where the answer will be stored and afterwards printed.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want a function that outputs a list of squared numbers.

```
def test(CATS=10):
    result = [] # empty list to store the squared numbers 
    cur_num =1
    while cur_num <= CATS:
        result.append(cur_num**2)
        cur_num += 1     
    return result 

# call the function and print result
print(test(10))
```

Comment: Actually it looks like what I need but for some reason it prints just "[1]"

Comment: I tried debugging it and follow it through but for some reason it stops after the first answer is appended

Comment: @helplessstudent Are you sure? print(test(10)) gave me [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100] in the terminal.